# Data structure for storing books using an array and a doubly linked list

Tags: c, arrays, list, data-structures

I am trying to create a data structure for a library program using an array and a linked list. The array's index represents the book ID and the element in the array represents the book quantity.

To keep track of which borrowers has a copy of each book, I want each index pointing to a linked list.

I already have the library files for the doubly (circular) linked list [clist].

To create a new clist:

```
clist *xs;
xs = new_clist();
```

The array for storing books is:

```
books[100]
```

Diagrammatically here is what i'm trying to do:

```
 i (qty) -> (list of borrowers)

 0  5    -> (1,5,6)
 1  8    -> ()
 2  6    -> (8,5)
 .  .     .
 .  .     .
 .  .     .
 99 7     ->(8,5,6)
```

I am struggling to program this data structure, I would be very grateful if somebody would show me how this could be done. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put the head node of your list into the book structure:

```
typedef struct _book_info
{
    unsigned int book_id;
    size_t quantity;
    clist * clients;
}book_info_t;

book_info_t books[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct book{
    int id;
    int quantity;
    struct client* borrowers;
};
```

And define your `borrower` structure as you like:

```
struct client{
    char* data;
    struct client* next;
    struct client* previous;
};
```

You could then initialize your book like this:

```
struct book b = {NULL};
b.id = 0;
b.quantity = 0;
b.borrowers = malloc (n * sizeof(client));
```